# Android: Draw circle in custom canvas on button click

Tags: android, canvas

I'm doing a simple drum set app where the users can click the button to make the corresponding sound and draw a circle on the canvas at a random location. For the canvas, I created a custom view called CanvasView, then I implements that CanvasView into the MainActivity, so I can control that View each time the buttons are clicked with OnClickListener in the MainActivity. 
However, I don't know how to actually control (draw a circle on) the CanvasView using the OnClickListener. I need help on this part
This is my code for the MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//setup variables for soundpool
.
.
.
//implements CanvasView

CanvasView mCanvasView;

//set up soundID for each sound
.
.  
.
//setup buttons
Button mKick;
.
. 
.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//set up soundpools 
.
. 
.

//example, the kick drum button
//kick drum
    mKick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kick);
    mKick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        soundPool.play(kick, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);

//          mCanvasView.draw(CanvasView.mCanvas);

    }
});
```

This is my code for the CanvasView

```
public class CanvasView extends View {
public Paint mPaint;
public static Canvas mCanvas;
//constructor
public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint();
}
//what I want to draw is here
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mCanvas = canvas;
    super.onDraw(mCanvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawCircle(30, 30, radius, mPaint);
```

This is my layout XML for the MainActivity

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:columnCount="3"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:rowCount="5"
tools:context=".GridXMLActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/kick"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|fill_vertical"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:text="Kick" />

<com.example.virtualdrumset.CanvasView
    android:id="@+id/canvasView1"
    android:layout_width="143dp"
    android:layout_height="169dp"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_row="0" />
```

I deeply apologize for any inconvenience or mistakes. This is my first time asking question.

Comment: I didn't understand your question properly. What do you mean by  `I don't know how to actually control (draw a circle on) the CanvasView using the OnClickListener.`. You want to draw a circle each time the button is clicked? Like draw 2nd circle on clicking button 2nd time, 3rd circle on clicking button 3rd time ??

Comment: Yes, what I want is to draw a circle each time the button is clicked, but refresh after each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call `onDraw` function of the `canvas` directly from the activity. Instead make a public method in the canvas view and write your logic there and call `invalidate` at the end. This calls `onDraw` method and contents are drawn on the screen again according to your new logic.

If you want a circle to be drawn at random locations on screen each time button is clicked you can do something like this

```
public class CanvasView extends View {
    public Paint mPaint;
    public static Canvas mCanvas;
    private int mPivotX = 0;
    private int mPivotY = 0;
    private int radius = 60;

    //constructor
    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint();
    }

    public void drawCircle() {

        int minX = radius * 2;
        int maxX = getWidth() - (radius *2 );

        int minY = radius * 2;
        int maxY = getHeight() - (radius *2 );

        //Generate random numbers for x and y locations of the circle on screen
        Random random = new Random();
        mPivotX = random.nextInt(maxX - minX + 1) + minX;
        mPivotY = random.nextInt(maxY - minY + 1) + minY;

        //important. Refreshes the view by calling onDraw function
        invalidate();

    }

    //what I want to draw is here
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mCanvas = canvas;
        super.onDraw(mCanvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawCircle(mPivotX, mPivotY, radius, mPaint);
    }
}
```

And then onButtonClick

```
mKick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        soundPool.play(kick, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);

          mCanvasView.drawCircle()

    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but the app crashed when I clicked, and the error log refers to the onclicklistener of the button

Comment: What is the exception? Can you post the full LogTrace of the exception?

Comment: Have you initialized `mCanvasView` in onCreate? `mCanvasView = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.canvasView1);`

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.virtualdrumset.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:111)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I apologize that I can not post the log properly due to the limitation of comment

Comment: That's fine. Have you initialized `mCanvasView` in onCreate? `mCanvasView = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.canvasView1);`

Comment: Edit: I forgot to init the CanvasView, it works now. Thank you very much